# How can I run java code that has been pasted into my program

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I'm making a simulator for Time Complexity. The purpose is that Students can choose which algorithms they want to compare.

But I want to make it possible to compare algorithms they've written themselves. I know how to get it to work with a compiled .class file.

I was wondering whether it is possible for the students to just paste the code (with predefined public methods) and then just run it.

I suppose that I have to do something with javac.

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) class. You will need to add tools.jar to your classpath if you don't already have it.

Comment: @James There ought to be a badge for that.